# DatagridView How to have a different row count per column?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

So I was trying to display my data in specific format in a `datagridview`.
So my format goes like this:

```
A B C

1 1 1

2 2 x

3 x x
```

the x means no cell.

As you can see each column has different row count. I want to achieve the same result in DatagridView or in any other control in the Dot Net Framework.

Comment: This is not possible at all as the DGV will always hold a 2d array. Of course it is up to you which cells to fill. -  You can have varying columncounts per item in  a listview as its items are a jagged array. So the effect shown is possible but only as lonf as the missing cells at at the end of each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [jdweng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43964895/3773066), if for some reason you truly want:

> [T]he x means no cell.

Then you can handle the `DataGridView.CellPainting` event to effectively hide the empty cell. Mind you, it will start to look *odd* when `null` cells are intermingled amidst valued cells - and not just at the row ends.

```
// ...
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, null, null });

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.dataGridView1.CellPainting += DataGridView1_CellPainting;
```

---

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

        if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value is DBNull)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Empty cell's painted like DGV background]

Comment: Wow this is truly the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");

            dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));

            dt.Columns["A"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dt.Columns["B"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dt.Columns["C"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,2,3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2, });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3 });

            datagridview1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Thanks that what i was looking for