# How do I hide a ComboBox on certain rows of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

After some work with Google I find the answer to this is to intercept the paint event, draw only the background and call it done.

This correctly disposed of the buttons and the checkbox on the rows in question but the ComboBoxes are now black squares and they are actually still there--you can drop them down.

Attempting to replace the offending items with DataGridViewTextBoxCells caused a crash in the paint routine.

I need to add some total rows mixed in with the data rows.  Completely non-interactive and most columns should just be blank.  How do I do it??

Comment: Have you tried using "Visible" property of the combobox?

Comment: When you hide the offending ComboBox on certain rows, what is your expected look of the remaining cell? That of an empty TextBoxCell? Making the entire cell [look non-existant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43986766/3773066)?

Comment: @FrancescoMilani The visible property of cells in a DataGridView is read only.

Comment: @OhBeWise Yeah, like an empty text cell.  The buttons and checkboxes worked fine, I just get white space.  The handlers see they are on a total row and immediately exit.  I have to provide an empty image for the column that contains graphics but that's no big deal.

Comment: what about something like this: cmbHidden.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
            cmbHidden.ReadOnly = true;

Comment: My apologies on my misguided answer. For some reason I mistook CheckBox for ComboBox when working a solution.

Comment: @OhBeWise When I was Googling about it everybody was talking about hiding checkboxes, not comboboxes.