# How to remove a cell programatically from DataGridView in Windows Forms using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

I need to remove a cell based on some condition from datagridview of windows forms.

below is my code.

```
private void grdvTest_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var grdv = sender as DataGridView;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdv.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCell BookButtonCell = row.Cells[0];
            ViewModelMyItem item = row.DataBoundItem as ViewModelMyItem;

            if (item.IsDeleted)
            {
                row.Cells.Remove(BookButtonCell);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex
    }
}
```

Error at:

```
row.Cells.Remove(BookButtonCell);
```

> Collection already belongs to a DataGridView control. This operation is no longer valid.

Comment: You can remove rows and columns, but not cells.

Comment: The DGV always has all cells in place. You can't 'remove' a Cell. You can replace it by another, empty cell, though.

Comment: All Rows must have equal number of cells so you cannot delete a cell, wich is logic.

Comment: @TaW: How can i replace the cell by empty cell? I am using DataGridViewImageCell.

Comment: Try:     `DataGridViewTextBoxCell tc = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    grdv[0, row] = tc;`

Comment: from a databound grid, you need to delete from datasource rather than Gridview.

Comment: Also: Instead of deleteng you can easily hide the column ` grdv.Columns[0].Visible = false;`

Comment: **`grdv.Columns[0].Visible = false;`**  this will hide the entire column. I just want to hide/delete cell on condition. @TaW

Comment: Right. Then did you try the other code snippet? Or Remove the Button text by setting the Cell's value!

Comment: `DataGridViewTextBoxCell tc = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); grdv[0, row] = tc;` i tried this. but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Here's another way I've done before using [`DataGridView.CellPainting`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43986766/3773066) to make a cell appear removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove cell after binding datasources to the gridview control, but you can handle it with different way if you want to hide the cell or **AccessibleObject** within that cell by initializing  a new cell like below.

```
rowdata.Cells[6] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
```

this will override your existing cell.